# list a few classes with one style

Tags: css

very simple question but i dont really get it to work. if i have a few classes, each one related to a div.

```
.div1 .div2 .div3 .div4 .div5 ...
```

but they all have the same css style for example

```
{ position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; ... }
```

shouldn i be able to write it like this in the css?

```
.div1 .div2 .div3 .div4 .div5 { position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; }
```

but it doestn work, i have to type:

```
.div1 { position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; }
.div2 { position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; }
....
```

ps. i could make one class and give it to all divs, but i need different!
thanks ted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to separate your classes with commas if you want them to have the same style :

```
.div1, .div2, .div3, .div4, .div5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
```